# Vector values in ICRF to calculate angular separation

Tags: python, skyfield

I'm trying to get my head around the concept of the values in ICRF.

I wanted to calculate the angular separation between 2 or more objects with a known R.A and Dec.

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740731/convert-a-direction-vector-to-r-a-and-dec-in-skyfield), I need to provide the x,y,x vector value for the objects, in order to use [separation_from](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.ICRF.separation_from) method in Skyfield.

Unfortunately I'm not really sure on how to get the x,y,z vector value for each of the object.

I've been using pyephem's ephem.separation with no issues, but I'm still couldn't get it done in skyfield.

Thanks